# Tortoise SVN Repository Creation: I get the wrong default folder structure

Tags: svn, repository, directory, tortoisesvn, creation

I am on Windows 10. I am using TortoiseSVN Version 1.10. I create a folder "SVNRepository. Right Click on the folder>TortoiseSVN>Create Repository Here.
[image]
so far so good. I click OK and then I get the following default structure instead of the structure trunk/branches/tag

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the actual repository itself, not your working directory. The directory you're looking at is where subversion will store all of your version history, logs, source code, etc in it's own database format (a series of deltas).

If this is a local repository on your computer, you can use the `file://` protocol to find the actual directory structure of your repository.

Typically the workflow will be that you develop on the *trunk* and *branches* of your repository, using the *tags* for "snapshots", if you will, of the repository at certain points in the development cycle (such as official releases). So do an `svn checkout` on `file:///C:/Path/to/my/repo/trunk` and you can begin there.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me solve this. To me the message and the manual are unclear about this.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted in the event this question comes up for other users in the future.

Comment: I didn't really understand, could you please point to a reference to further understand?